# Plot categorical data with matplotlib - transposed pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, transpose

I have data for two groups in a pandas dataframe, with for each group the mean of 3 different items of a scale:

```
        item1       item2       item3   
group                   
1       2.807692    3.115385    3.923077    
2       2.909091    2.454545    3.909091
```

I would like to plot the means for both groups in a bar plot. I found some code for doing just that [here](https://www.datascience.com/blog/learn-data-science-intro-to-data-visualization-in-matplotlib) with the following function:

```
def groupedbarplot(x_data, y_data_list, y_data_names, colors, x_label, y_label, title):
_, ax = plt.subplots()
# Total width for all bars at one x location
total_width = 0.5
# Width of each individual bar
ind_width = total_width / len(y_data_list)
# This centers each cluster of bars about the x tick mark
alteration = np.arange(-(total_width/2), total_width/2, ind_width)
    # Draw bars, one category at a time
for i in range(0, len(y_data_list)):
    # Move the bar to the right on the x-axis so it doesn't
    # overlap with previously drawn ones
    ax.bar(x_data + alteration[i], y_data_list[i], color = colors[i], label = y_data_names[i], width = ind_width)
ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
ax.set_xlabel(x_label)
ax.set_title(title)
ax.legend(loc = 'upper right')
```

This is working perfectly fine with the mentioned dataframe, however, instead of having the bars for all items grouped together per group I wanted the bars to be grouped per item so I can see for each item the difference per groups. Therefore, I've transposed the dataframe, but this is giving me errors when plotting:

```
groupedbarplot(x_data = data.index.values
           , y_data_list = [data[1],data[2]]
           , y_data_names = ['group1', 'group2']
           , colors = ['blue', 'orange']
           , x_label = 'Scale'
           , y_label = 'Score'
           , title = 'title')

      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-b910d304a19e> in <module>()
    5                , x_label = 'Verloning scale'
    6                , y_label = 'Score'
----> 7                , title = 'Score op elke item voor werknemer en oud-werknemers')

<ipython-input-66-9fa4a515d5e9> in groupedbarplot(x_data, y_data_list, y_data_names, colors, x_label, y_label, title)
      11         # Move the bar to the right on the x-axis so it doesn't
      12         # overlap with previously drawn ones
 ---> 13         ax.bar(x_data + alteration[i], y_data_list[i], color = colors[i], label = y_data_names[i], width = ind_width)
      14     ax.set_ylabel(y_label)
      15     ax.set_xlabel(x_label)

TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly
```

I have checked all variable to see where the difference is, but can't seem to find it. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd be useful to have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

When I transpose the dataframe you provide the result looks like this

```
          1         2
item1  2.807692  2.909091
item2  3.115385  2.454545
item3  3.923077  3.909091
```

therefore `data.index.values` returns `array(['item1', 'item2', 'item3'], dtype=object)`, and I suspect that your error results from `x_data + alteration[i]` which tries to add a float to your array which contains strings.